# $_post with foreach loop between array not working

Tags: php

I have two files:
 1) `login.html`:

```
<form method = "POST" action="procesare.php">
Username: <input type="text" name="nume_utilizator"/>
<br/>
Parola: <input type="password" name="parola"/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value = "Trimite"/>
```

2) `procesare.php`...that is not working:

```
$utilizatori_aplicatie = array(
    'Ion' => '1234',
    'Vasile' => '1234',
    'Jimmy' => '5678'
);
$nume_utilizator = $_POST['nume_utilizator'];
$parola = $_POST['parola'];

foreach($utilizatori_aplicatie as $username => $password)
    {
    if ($nume_utilizator == $username && $parola == $password)
        {
        echo 'FELICITARI!<br/>';
        }
    }

echo "Bine ai venit, " . $nume_utilizator . "!<br/>";
echo "Parola ta este: " . $parola . "<br/>";
```

I want to output...

```
 Ion or Vasile or Jimmy with their passwords with  
 FELICITARI!
 "Bine ai venit, ...name of the user
```

...when a user enters one of those names.

How can I do this with my code?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Could you add print_r($_POST) to the beginning of the script and re-run after entering a correct username and password? It would be good to see that the form was properly sending the names through. I suspect you not closing your form tag is the issue but this could eliminate that as a possibility.

Comment: this is the error: Notice: Undefined index: nume_utilizator in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\ziua_15\ex2\procesare.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: parola in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\ziua_15\ex2\procesare.php on line 15
Bine ai venit, !
Parola ta este:

Comment: I tested the code and it outputs: `FELICITARI!
Bine ai venit, Ion!
Parola ta este: 1234`.
As Acey said, print_r($_POST) at top of procesare.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to access the php file directly, you'll get the errors. To avoid the errors, initialize your variables and then set the value equal to post values if they exist. You can check for values before echo statements also if you do not want to echo them in certain cases.

```
$utilizatori_aplicatie = array(
            'Ion' => '1234',
            'Vasile' => '1234',
            'Jimmy' => '5678'
        );
    $nume_utilizator ='';
    $parola = '';
    if(!empty($_POST['nume_utilizator'])){
        $nume_utilizator = $_POST['nume_utilizator'];
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['parola'])){
        $parola = $_POST['parola'];
    }

        foreach($utilizatori_aplicatie as $username => $password)
            {
            if ($nume_utilizator == $username && $parola == $password)
                {
                echo 'FELICITARI!<br/>';
                }


              }

if(!empty($parola) && !empty($nume_utilizator)){
            echo "Bine ai venit, " . $nume_utilizator . "!<br/>";
            echo "Parola ta este: " . $parola . "<br/>";
}
else{
echo "Please access this page via login.html and make sure you enter the values of both username and password.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks user1439090...and thanks all for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I can't see this in code you have provided, which is quite important, but close the form tag.